# Pluggable-app-style for angularjs website

Tags: angularjs, plugins

We are building a website allowing 3rd party (ourselves included) to write plugins and install into the platform. Basically, you can imagine of wordpress written in angularjs, and webmasters have options of install modules (for example  Q&A , forum/whatever) into it.

I am thinking about something like this. Using server code to create main-app code (app.js as in standard naming)

```
angular.module("thePlatform", [
    'plugin.forum',
    'plugin.musicStore',
    'plugin.whatever' 
]);

whereas forum/musicStore/whatever are plugin that can be installed/unsinstalled into the platform.
```

Is that a good choice ? Or should we go for the SinglePage-Solution like that? If you have better approach, please !

Note: I did google before asking but couldn't find any answer:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/239056/angularjs-structuring-a-web-application-with-multiple-ng-apps

[AngularJS websites: single SPA vs multiple SPA apps/components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880018/angularjs-websites-single-spa-vs-multiple-spa-apps-components)

Comment: Did you find the approach that suited you ? I'm in similar situation and  trying to find a good one ?

Comment: @khorvat : I ended up with multiple separated angular apps for each "forum" , "store", etc... It means Forum app will be something like /forum/index.php (html, java whatever), and for album at /album/index.php

Comment: So you ended up using diff folders and php to solve this. Ok that may be one solution. Thanks